# How to count number of decreasing point?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count how many large decreasing point before the last point.

Let say I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[('2000-09-29 22:00:00'), 78.48659257615778],
       [('2000-09-29 23:00:00'), 79.46896724006444],
       [('2000-09-30 00:00:00'), 79.74108445117001],
       [('2000-09-30 01:00:00'), 79.59727418822389],
       [('2000-09-30 02:00:00'), 79.73048396364723],
       [('2000-09-30 03:00:00'), 79.09930124357557],
       [('2000-09-30 04:00:00'), 78.28903340851555],
       [('2000-09-30 05:00:00'), 78.12229420958224],
       [('2000-09-30 06:00:00'), 78.89923606080113],
       [('2000-09-30 07:00:00'), 78.9620439478767],
       [('2000-09-30 08:00:00'), 78.92566676678388],
       [('2000-09-30 09:00:00'), 61.74819886499889],
       [('2000-09-30 10:00:00'), 35.235524848405]])
df.columns = ['DATE', 'V1']

plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']), df['V1'], marker='.', markersize=8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to get the count how many point have large deviate before the last point.
In this case it will give one point that decreasing largely before the last point.

Comment: you will need to define "large deviate" somehow.

Comment: From visually, I would say the large deviate are around -26.5 units. but it will troublesome if I'm dealing with a lot of variables and I need to define different deviate value for each variables.

Comment: so you might wanna go with something like 3 or 5 standard deviations...

Comment: sorry i dont get your point. How to implement the standard deviation in order to find the point have large deviate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using the differences and standard deviation:

```
df["dv"]= df.V1.diff()
df.loc[df.dv.lt(df.dv.mean()-df.dv.std())]   

                            V1         dv
DATE                                     
2000-09-30 09:00:00  61.748199 -17.177468
2000-09-30 10:00:00  35.235525 -29.764475
```

The intervall can be narrowed, too, if you select the values next to the min value (or the last one), and apply the code above:

```
df= df.set_index("DATE").loc[df.V1.idxmin()-pd.Timedelta("3 hours"):]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar idea as in [mcsoini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124822/3944322), we can write:

```
# calculate threshold as mean minus two standard deviations
th = df.V1[:-1].mean() - 2 * df.V1[:-1].std()
# count values below this threshold
df[:-1].V1[df.V1<th].count()
```

(as per the OP question the last point is excluded, hence [:-1])